Is there a more efficient way of extracting the payload and deserializing into an object from response body
I am interfacing with some 3rd party APIs to retrieve data and given that it was a successful response with the expected payload, it will always come in the following JSON structure as below
{
  "data": "{...}"
  "meta": "{...}"
  "dictionaries": "{...}"
}

I call the API and retrieve the entire body as below
@Autowired
public ObjectMapper mapper;

@Autowired
public WebClient webClient;

public Mono<Car> getAirBounds(ApiRequest request) {
    Mono<AirboundResponse> responseBody = webClient.post()
            .uri("some url")
            .body(Mono.just(request), ApiRequest.class)
            .exchangeToMono(this::handleResponse)
            .flatMap(resp -> {
                try {
                    Car node =  mapper.treeToValue(resp.get("data"), Car.class);
                    return Mono.just(node);
                } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            });
    return responseBody;
}

private Mono<JsonNode> handleResponse(ClientResponse response) {
    if (response.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
        return response.bodyToMono(JsonNode.class);
    } 
    else if (response.statusCode().is4xxClientError()) {
        // Handle client errors (e.g., 404 Not Found)
        return response.bodyToMono(JsonNode.class);
        //return Mono.error(new Exception("Employee not found"));
    } 
    else if (response.statusCode().is5xxServerError()) {
        // Handle server errors (e.g., 500 Internal Server Error)
        return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Server error"));
    } 
    else {
        // Handle other status codes as needed
        return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Unexpected error"));
    }
}

The payload that I want to deserialize exists in the attribute "data", but the value itself can be different JSON formats (not just of type Car as in the code snippet above). I know the format that the expected payload of "data" will be depending on the API endpoint that I am calling.
I am wondering is there a more efficient way of doing this instead of deserializing the entire response first into JsonNode and then using the ObjectMapper once again to read the JsonNode back into the Java object.
